# Expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection'

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I want to generate database from model Entity Framework 6 with mysql.
I add all library of mysql to referacen and configuration file app.conf

[image: this is the .dll in reference]

and this is configuration file app.conf

```
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

but in the end I have this problem

[image]

I save and rebuild restart visual but no sloved

Comment: This seems to be an accidental issue, you can report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Answer (score 5):

restart the visual studio and it will work. have faced the same many times.

Comment: at this point its not even funny, but it works

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to append to the connection string:

```
initial catalog=YOUR_DB_NAME
```

Comment: Please double check my edit and make sure it is correct

Comment: @mozway i believe it is